# porting web app to Tomcat: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jdbc, web.xml

New user of Tomcat (8.5.9) on Linux CentOS 7 with Java SE 8. I must be making a simple mistake. This should be a textbook example how to configure a JDBC connection pool for tomcat.

I have this error:

`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/pool1] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]`

Any idea what I could doing wrong? Tomcat [states](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html) `It is NOT recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file.` Thus, my setup:

$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/META-INF/context.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/pool1"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="xx"
            password="xx"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            url="xx"
            maxTotal="256"
            maxIdle="8"
            initialSize="4"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="7200"
            removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"/>

  <Resource name="jdbc/pool2"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="xx"
            password="xx"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            url="xx"
            maxTotal="256"
            maxIdle="8"
            initialSize="4"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="7200"
            removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"/>

  <ResourceLink name="jdbc/pool1"
                global="jdbc/pool1"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

  <ResourceLink name="jdbc/pool2"
                global="jdbc/pool2"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/web.xml is as follows:

```
...
<resource-ref>
        <description>xxx</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/pool1</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>xxx</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/pool1</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
 ...
```

The code causing the exception:

```
 Context context = new InitialContext();
 DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/pool1");
 conn = ds.getConnection();
```

I have not modified $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml at all. Did I configure something incorrectly, or am I missing setting another file up somewhere?

UPDATE 1

I tried adding the above ResourceLinks to the GlobalNamingResources tag in the $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml file, then stopping/starting Tomcat, but I got the same error.

UPDATE 2

I then added the Resource tags from context.xml above also to the server.xml file (GlobalNamingResources tag), stopping/starting tomcat, and got same error.

UPDATE 3

I got everything working with Andreas' expert help (thanks!) by changing the way java calls the pool:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context context = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/pool1");
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Also, the ResourceLinks should not be in server.xml (they simply generate a warning in tomcat log).

Comment: What code is throwing the exception?

Comment: @EJP Sure, I added the code throwing the exception just above Update 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` file should contain the full `<Resource>` element. Remember to also add the JDBC driver jar file to Tomcat's `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` folder, since it is Tomcat, not your webapp, that needs it when the `<Resource>` is defined in `server.xml`.

Next, the `META-INF/context.xml` is a template that is used the *first* time your webapp is deployed. It gets copied to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`, and is likely not updated/refreshed if you change `META-INF/context.xml`.

The `.../Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml` file should contain the `<ResourceLink>` element, mapping the name used by the webapp to the name used in `server.xml`. Keeping those two names the same is easiest, but not required.

Tomcat works fine without the `<resource-ref>` elements in `WEB-INF/web.xml`, but it's better if they are there, for compatibility with other Servlet containers.

*Note:* `$CATALINA_BASE` is usually the same as `$CATALINA_HOME`, i.e. the folder where Tomcat is installed, unless you explicitly configure it otherwise.

So, `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server ...>
    ...
    <GlobalNamingResources>
        ...
        <Resource name="jdbc/pool1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" ... />
        <Resource name="jdbc/pool2" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" ... />
        ...
    </GlobalNamingResources>
    ...
</Server>
```

and `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/pool1" global="jdbc/pool1" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/pool2" global="jdbc/pool2" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

and place `ojdbcXXX.jar` in `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`.

Comment: Thanks @Anderas, (1) `server.xml` file contains full `<Resource>` elements, as does `context.xml` (2) Oracle's `ojdbc.jar` file is in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` folder, (3) I have not defined `$CATALINA_BASE` so it should default to `$CATALINA_HOME`, (4) there are no files located in the folder `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina/localhost`, is Tomcat supposed to put something there?

Comment: Maybe that has changed. It used to copy the `META-INF/context.xml` file there, named after the webapp, `myapp.xml` in your case. Try doing that yourself. I never use `META-INF/context.xml`, always a manually configured `conf/catalina/localhost/myapp.xml` file, since it depends on how the `server.xml` file was configured.

Comment: And remember to restart Tomcat when making changes to `conf` files (incl. subfolders).

Comment: From http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html (Defining a Context section): `Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined: In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.`

Comment: `[enginename]` = `Catalina` *(from `<Engine name="Catalina">` in server.xml)*, and `[hostname]` = `localhost` *(from `<Engine ... defaultHost="localhost">` and `<Host name="localhost">`, unless you're doing virtual hosting in Tomcat)*.

Comment: With update 1 and 2 above, I copied the context.xml file above to be `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`, stopped/started tomcat, and still gives same error.

Comment: Then maybe you're doing it wrong in the Java code. Did you do `initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env").lookup("jdbc/pool1")`? Show code. See [Apache Tomcat 8 - JNDI Resources HOW-TO - Using resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Using_resources).

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, that was it! I ported the working code from a GlassFish deployment. Looks like there are some differences in the way the Java code calls them. I added UPDATE 3 above to show the working code.