# How to configure a connection pool to a DB2 database in a Tomcat Java web app

Tags: java, tomcat, db2, tomcat9

I am trying to define a connection pool to a **DB2** database from a **Java** application deployed in **Tomcat**.

There is something in the next 3 pieces that does not fit.

**web.xml:**

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Connection pool to SFEAAPPDB database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/SFEAAPPDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**context.xml:**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/SFEAAPPDB"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
    url="jdbc:db2://someplacesomewhere.es:50001/DESA"
    username="admin"
    password="admin"
    />
```

**source.java:**

```
String poolName = "jdbc/SFEAAPPDB";
DataSource ds = new InitialContext().lookup(poolName);
```

What should be the correct value for the '**poolName**' variable?

Comment: What is the issue that you have? Please be specific

Comment: I get this error: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: El nombre [jdbc/SFEAAPPDB] no este asociado a este contexto

Comment: Then your question should be about that error, not as a how-to. Please add the full error to the question. If there are more lines or details also add them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [porting web app to Tomcat: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516977/porting-web-app-to-tomcat-javax-naming-namenotfoundexception)

Comment: You can also review the Tomcat official documentation describing how to create [and then how to use](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources) a resource. Note the use of the `java:` prefix, and "_the standard `java:comp/env` naming context ... is the root of all provided resource factories_".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all..

With help from here and there, I was solving an error, but another one appeared.

Finally, this is how all the elements involved were left:

**Java source:**

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context context = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/SFEAAPPDB");
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

**...APACHE\conf\Catalina\localhost\sfeaapp.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/SFEAAPPDB" global="jdbc/SFEAAPPDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>   
</Context>
```

**...APACHE\conf\server.xml:**

```
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/SFEAAPPDB"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
    url="jdbc:db2://someplacesomewhere.es:50001/DESA:useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=false;"
    username="admin"
    password="admin"
    />
```

Also:
**db2jcc4.jar** in ...APACHE\lib\

And note that you must put a semicolon after the last value too in: **jdbc:db2://someplacesomewhere.es:50001/DESA:useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=false;**